# How to get a list of the jar included in the uberjar build by maven shade plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a (long) list of what should not be included in my uber-jar, and I would like the list of what is included, so that I can work on the configuration and remove duplicates.

I looked at the output printed by `mvn package` that lists a lot of

```
[INFO] Including aaa.bbb:ccc.ddd:jar:x.y.z in the shaded jar
```

but I am pretty sure some of those were not included when I used the `minimizeJar` option. And looking into the output jar only allows to know the included classes (very difficult to track w.r.t the dependencies)

**Question:** Which ever configuration I use, how can I get a list of the dependencies that are actually merged into the uberjar?

Comment: Already the list of what is *not* included will give you hints about where you tweak the configuration or remove dependencies from the project?

Comment: All information can be good, but not really. What I am looking for is an easy way to check whether all dep present in a deployment cluster are not included in the fat-jar, but there are tones of dep in the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `maven-shade-plugin`, but have you tried out [mvn dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)? It should list all dependencies and its subdependencies of your project.

Edit: I re-read your question and it seems that you need a full dependency tree of your final uber-jar. A quick look at the `maven-shade-plugin` page told me that any dependency will be packed into the uber-jar. This should be what `mvn dependency:tree` outputs, but you can [list the jar's contents](https://mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/) aswell with `jar tf <uber-jar>.jar`. You may have to filter out parent dirs (e. g. com/) and the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer I am looking for, but for the sake of information sharing, here is what I did to find which dependency to remove from the shaded-jar:

- use `mvn dependency:list > dep.list`

  - then manually remove lines that are not dependencies
  - and sort it
- visually make a diff with the list of jar present on the deployment cluster
- use `mvn dependency:tree` and my head to find the parent most dependencies that can be removed
- mark them as `<scope>provided<scope/>`
- use `<keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>` in the shade plugin configuration

Tedious...